# how can I select Animation in Action Editor (Blender Python)

Tags: python, animation, scripting

i have a tiny problem, i search a Python Command the in [Dope Sheet > Action Editor]
choose/select a Animation (in Collection).

i saw the Python access **bpy.data.actions["Walk_Anim"]** but i can't find the exact reference.

her one example by my problem:

i use Blender v2.78 and i have the Animation:

1. " **Crouch_Anim** "
2. " **Idle_Stand** "
3. " **Jump_Up** "
4. " **Walk_Anim** "

my Skeleton use now "**Walk_Anim**" but i wish try to set him on "**Idle_Stand**" (but only with a Python Command)

my question is now, how is the right Python Command for the selecting the Animation in the Collection.

best regards
- TheDevil

P.s. i'm a newbie in BPy

Answer (score 2):

The action editor displays the action of the currently selected object. Each object can only have one active action.

To alter the action used by an object, which is then displayed in the action editor, set the objects action property. The [`action`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.AnimData.html#bpy.types.AnimData.action) is found in the objects [`animation_data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.animation_data)

```
bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.action['Idle_Stand']
```

Comment: I had to use bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.get("Idle_Stand") to select an action